# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20 when select item from spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-spinner

when i select from spinner first time every thing is good when select second time all good
but after that when select from it , it show that error

E/AndroidRuntime(10594): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20

```
public static ArrayList<String> s=new ArrayList<String>();

for(........
s.add(e.child(2).text());
                                    }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    try{
        editPrice.setText(""+Splash.s.get(pos));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"The country is "+pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Java arrays are indexed from `0`, so `20-th` element will have index `19`.

Comment: Support some more of your code and format it properly, then we may help with more exact answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java indexing starts from 0. So if the array has **20** elements, its indexes are from **0** to **19**.

Take for the example this String array:

```
Values:   A, B, C, D, E     -    length: 5
Indexes:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4

String valueInFIRSTposition= stringArray.get(0); //stringArray[0] for arrays
String valueInSECONDposition= stringArray.get(1); //stringArray[1] for arrays
...
String valueInLASTposition= stringArray.get(stringArray.size()-1); //stringArray[stringArray.length-1] for array
```

So if you want to fetch for example "C", you would fetch index with number 2:

```
String valueInThirdPosition= stringArray.get(2); //stringArray[2] for arrays
```

Also, when writing a **for loop** that iterates over an array, it would look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
    Object value= array.get(i);
}
```

So **the first** index is **0**, to fetch **the first** element of an array. In the middle part of the for loop (`i<array.size(0)`) which is the condition to say **WHEN** the for loop ends you see that it ends **BEFORE** the last index - for the reasons stated above.

Comment: public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
    long id) 

that pos  in spinner begin from 0 also

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you are trying to access the 21th element (index 20) of an array containing only 20 elements.

You have to correct your code so that this case does not occur.

Comment: the array has 20 item - 0 to 19

how can i get i try pos-1  i get error 
   editPrice.setText(""+Splash.s.get(pos));

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener

you should use `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)` to retrieve your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is sample example for spinner

final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_experience);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.experience_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                Object test = spinner.getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this, "The planet is " +
                        spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
```